# Classic phone with Linux backup/restore

Tags: linux, mobile-phone

I'm looking for a not so smart, classic phone mainly used for calls and SMS.

Requirements:

- backup and restore contacts, messages etc. with a PC running Linux
- high quality and durable construction
- good call sound quality
- MP3 audio support with 3.5mm jack
- microSD card support for MP3 files
- microUSB charger
- price range up to $100

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirements it may just be easier to get an Android smart phone.

You can backup your contacts and numbers to a Google Account , standard smart phones will have a microSD card slot, a 3.5mm headphone jack and high quality sound.
I suggest the Lenovo A806
Specs are here: http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_golden_warrior_a8-6529.php